# Access a detached fragment's view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I currently am using ActionBar's tab feature with multiple fragments each representing a tab.

On my last fragment there is a 'Submit' button that takes all the input that the user has done on all the fragments and submits it.

My problem is that since those other fragments have been detached (only the currently showing fragment is attached to the main view) their view gets destroyed so cannot be accessed using the fragment's findViewById().

How can I access the data the user inputted for these fragments? Interestingly, it does store all the inputted values in a bundle and restores them when the fragment is attached again, I'm thinking the answer lies somewhere there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by not calling .detach() but .hide().

Now in the activity findViewById() will actually be able to access the view of all its fragments since their UI is now not detached just not showing.

Comment: can you explain where exactly did you replace the `.detach()` with `.hide()`. I am facing the same problem and need a solution.

Comment: When you write code to display another fragment you must call that fragment's hide() method as far as I remember.